# measuring the shape of moon by matlab

Tags: image-processing, matlab, measurement

I am doing a measuring project and I should measure the the width of moon crescent every night and make a plot of them by time. I searched the web but I didn't find useful thing. I want to know about what resources(Matlab , Image processing , ...) I should study.
I know about doing general works by Matlab, but I don't have any information about image processing in it. please help me !

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: http://www.mathworks.com/help/sl3d/examples/planetary-system.html ?

Comment: 1. By some type of edge-detector find Moon's edges. 2. Find corners of crescent by look-up of edge points. 3. Divide edge points by inner and outer borders. 4. Approximate borders by ellipses. 5. Compute crescent's area.  Another variant: get outer edge of Moon image and reconstruct full disk; count number of crescent's pixels and divide them on number of pixels inside full disk.

Comment: francesco : No . I am talking about image processing with matlab !

Comment: Since the moon is probably the brightest object in the images, I'd guess that the mean image intensity, or the number of bright pixels, is a pretty good proxy for the width of the crescent. You could calibrate this using images of the full and new moon.